# is there a count_if function for a gsl_vector? C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, gsl, countif

I am using the gnu scientific library (GSL).
Say I have a `gsl_vector` like this:
7  0  -6  5  8  0  10  -2

That's a vector containing positive numbers, negative numbers, and zeros as elements.

I want to count the number of non-zero elements or zero elements in this `gsl_vector`.
I know there is a function called `count_if` for a C++ Vector. But I search through the `gsl_vector.h` and `gsl_blas.h`, there is no function equal to that.
I can go though all the elements by assessing them though `gsl_vector_get()` and then ask the if question.

```
int counter = 0;

for(int i = 0;i<length_of_the_gsl_vector;++i){ 
  if(fabs(gsl_vector_get(y,i))<0.5) ++counter;
}

return counter;
```

But I have been wondering for almost a day whether there is such a function already in GSL that is much more efficient.

Or maybe there is a `count_if` function for `gsl_array` ?

Comment: gsl_vector_get does index validation, that's going to be the main performance killer

Comment: sure, and that's why I wanna go around it. I also searched for a conversion from gsl_vector to a C++ Vector so that I can use the count_if function in C++, but without success yet.

Comment: An array should really be accessible (as they state) with std::valarray model. Such statement authorize you to use std::iterators and std::count_if (with lambda, if possible).

Comment: I am not sure that I understand you. first, how can I convert a gsl_vector to an array? And second how does the count_if function works for an array? Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can get hold of the data pointer by using `gsl_vector_ptr`, then use `std::count_if` on pointers:

```
struct Predicate{
    inline bool operator()(double x) const {
        return fabs(x) < 0.5 ;
    }
} ;

int res = std::count_if( 
    gsl_vector_ptr(y,0), gsl_vector_ptr(y,0) + size, 
    Predicate()
) ;
```

Comment: thank you very much. on my computer I have to use gel_vector_ptr(y,0), gel_vector_ptr(y, size-1) instead. the result is always one less than the result should be. And I compared the time used with the primitive method I presented earlier. they differ slightly and the primitive method performed a heart bit faster...

Comment: I have edited the answer to use `gsl_vector_get` correctly. Also using a functor to remove issues with dereferencing the function pointer. This version should perform better.

Comment: no, the gsl_vector_get plus if method still is slightly faster. Besides, I don't know what went wrong here, the result still is one count less than it should be.

Answer (score 1):

They [state](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Vector-and-Matrix-References-and-Further-Reading.html) that GSL implements std::[valarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/valarray) model, I read such statement as authorizing me to use something like:

```
gsl_block vec;
/* initialize ... */
std::valarray<double> a(vec.data, vec.size);
/* use std:: galore */
```

Comment: of course, how could I forget there is another type called block in GSL. But well, this is embarrassing, I do not speak the language that well to get the solution you are implying. It'd be very kind if you could show me a small code like Romain did.